# Windows simultaneous physical drive access

Tags: windows, file-io

I can't seem to find the answer to this question. Can Windows simultaneously read/write to two physically separate disk drives (two drive letters, non RAID)? Obviously you can read/write applications, files, etc in what appears to be simultaneous mode. But are the requests truly running concurrently or are the requests alternating?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not completely up to Windows. Also, there's more than one interface from Windows to the physical drive ( ie the driver-to-endpoint-buffer, endpoint-buffer-to-SATA-controller, etc ). the answer to your question is probably yes, but your question is slightly vague.

Both drives can be reading or writing something from their buffer to disk at the same time.

Both drives can probably be transferring data to the SATA-controller to the same time.

Whether or not the data will be read by the CPU at the same time depends how many 
SATA-to-CPU or SATA-to-memory busses there are and whether or not the CPU has more than one core.

In any case, there can be more than one read/write operations going on at once, but they're almost always divided among different software threads and hardware buses. This is usually okay because hard disk drives take a *long* time to read and write compared to how quickly the CPU can multiplex their interfaces.

Tangential fact: a single SATA device *cannot* physically perform read and write operations simultaneously. This may become relevant to your question if you have multiple partitions on the same disk.